# how to insert a word in between () using regular expression

Tags: grails, groovy

How to insert a text in between of left & right Parentheses using groovy regular expressions

Ex: def myText = abc

expected output: (abc)

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

How about this? ;)

`"($myText)"`